# Creating a empty var I can populate based on different stored procedures within an if statement

Tags: c#, list, variables

I'm wondering if its possible to create an empty var I can fill with lists created from stored procedures within an if statement that has different data types? So something like

```
var results;

if(something == true)
{
    results = myStoredProcedure1(filter1, filter2).ToList();
}
else
{
    results = myStoredProcedure2(filter).ToList();
}
```

Comment: `List<string> results;`

Comment: Create an interface both types returned from the stored procedures implement.

Comment: It's not possible, See the [var documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var). When you declare a variable with `var`, you have to assigned a value in the same statement.

Comment: Imagine that would work as you think: how would you use that object, when you don´t know anything about it at **compile**-time? How would you call any of its members? It´s simply not possible.

Comment: If list item types are totally different, there are `object` and `IEnumerable`/`IList` (non-generic ones). But it depends on how do you plan to use the results.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved in multiple ways. Here are 3:

1. Only works if the `result` of both stored procedures return the same type, or that both return types inherit from a common base type or implement the same interface.

```cs
BaseObject results;
if (something) // No need to check '== true'
{
    results = myStoredProcedure1(filter1, filter2).ToList();
}
else
{
    results = myStoredProcedure2(filter).ToList();
}
```

You cannot declare the variable with `var`, because the C# type checker doesn't time travel. Meaning, on line 1 (`var results`) the program has no idea what type it is, and as such can't do anything with it. On the other hand, if we explicitly tell it what type it is, it can do something (e.g for structs it can allocate the required memory). Or as [HimBromBeere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2528063/himbrombeere) put it in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65288476/creating-a-empty-var-i-can-populate-based-on-different-stored-procedures-within#comment115422814_65288476)

> Imagine that would work as you think: how would you use that object, when you don´t know anything about it at **compile**-time? How would you call any of its members? It´s simply not possible.

---

2. Make the `results` a simple `object`

```cs
object results;
if (something) ...
```

This isn't frowned up as much as `dymanic` but it's still *very* bad, as you would later on need to cast it back to what it actually was, depending on the same condition. For example

```cs
if (something)
{
    var r = (SomeType) results);
    // To something with r
}
else
{
    var r = (SomeOtherType) results;
    // Do something with r
}
```

Which creates 2 paths with almost the same code, which is what you're trying to avoid (I think)

---

3. You could make it dynamic (but that is heavily frowned upon in the C#/ .NET world)
   dynamic results.

```cs
dynamic results;
if (something) ...
```

The massive downside with this is that you now have no idea what type the object is, meaning you just threw all of your type-safety out of the window.

Answer (score 0):

`var` is telling the compiler to work out what the type is, in your case there compiler cannot work it out because you do not give it anything to work with when you declare your variable.

If you want to do something like that you need to find an interface that both your results type use. This could be something like `IList` or if necessary `object`.

However both of these will limit what you can do afterwards unless you start checking the type to determine which you have, and unboxing to do what you want.

The better option may be to refactor to have separate functions to do your procedures and handle the results.

Answer (score 0):

you cant define an uninitialized `var` because it needs to have a type which will be generated at compile time.

Means, when you build the project that has `var x = 0;`, the compiler will change it to
`int x = 0;` which will not be possible in the case you're referring to.

So, in order to achieve that case you're looking for, you can use `dynamic`, for example

```
dynamic results;

if(something == true)
{
    results = myStoredProcedure1(filter1, filter2).ToList();
}
else
{
    results = myStoredProcedure2(filter).ToList();
}
```

and later on you can cast the dynamic object to whatever type you want to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use var itself, here is another option:

```
var results = new  Object();
```

Consider making interface or base class as recommended by other answers.

Answer (score 0):

If the lists returned by myStoredProcedure1 and myStoredProcedure2 are of the same type, you could use the ?: operator (`condition ? consequent : alternative`) instead of if/else, like this:

`var results = something ? myStoredProcedure1(filter1, filter2).ToList() : myStoredProcedure2(filter).ToList();`